# Does"cookie-cut" has other meaning except the one related to cookie and pastry?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does cookie-cut mean here? What is he trying to say?

> I think you can either look for forms, you can do specific reading
>      for them, or the forms can be demanded by what you want to say. And
>      when the material in poetry seems under almost unbearable pressure
>      you wonder whether the form hasn’t **cookie-cut** what the poet
>      wanted to say. But you chose the couplet, didn’t you, and some of
>      your freest passages are in couplets.

*From ["Robert Lowell, The Art of Poetry No. 3"](https://www.theparisreview.org/interviews/4664/robert-lowell-the-art-of-poetry-no-3-robert-lowell)*

Comment: Giving sources sometimes help getting answers. From an [interview of the American poet Robert Lowell](https://www.theparisreview.org/interviews/4664/robert-lowell-the-art-of-poetry-no-3-robert-lowell).

Comment: @Laure thanks, but I was reading this actually.and didn't get this part of the interview

Comment: cookie-cut in this case might mean that **couplets** have predetermined (eg. idiomatic) understandings. Quite the ironic question. It means the intended meaning would be counterintuitive to most *house-hold* readers.

Comment: A similar word is [*cookie-cutter*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cookie-cutter), adjective definitions 1 or 2. Might work in your context.

Comment: I think what Laure was trying to say is that you should add where you found this text to the question to help the folks trying to answer it. I went ahead and edited it in for you. See [So, you found a sentence or phrase… (Why you should cite your source)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie cutter imposes a specific form on the nebulas mass of dough.

A poet has innumerable ways of conveying their message. However, there are common forms that are familiar and one might fit their message to a convenient, recognizable form.  However, this poet chose to use couplets.  Couplets allow more freedom of expression; allow her/him to avoid "falling into" the use of overused, trite, or common forms of expressing a given idea or message.